# Powershell script: read an AD attribute and set is an environment variable

Tags: powershell, active-directory, environment-variables

I have a problem with some old apps and I need to set an environment variable from AD (hurray)

I'm quite new to PS scripting, so I can use some help.

In my AD I have filled the attribute `departmentNumber` with information, that part works fine.

Now I need to create a logon script which reads this field from the current user (attribute:  `departmentNumber`, derived from: `inetOrgPersonUser`) and set this as an environment variable called `AFDELING`.

I know this can be done using a VB script, but I prefer PS. Can anyone help me with this one?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Working with environment variables in PowerShell involves the special variable `$Env` and unfortunately you need to use a .NET method to set environment variables as no cmdlet exists (at least as of v2):

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("AFDELING", "DeptNo", "User")
```

The first string parameter is the variable name, the second is the value and the third is basically the persistance level requested for the variable: `Machine`, `User` or `Process` - both machine and user will survive a reboot and future applications will have access to them, though you will need to be running PowerShell with an administrative account to modify the machine-level variables.

Getting the user info should be equally easy. There are a variety of ways that you can access Active Directory, though one of the simplest in your case would be to use the [System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx) class:

```
$de = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$DeptNo = $de.Properties["departmentNumber"]
```

That should query the current user record from a domain controller, and assign the value from the departmentNumber attribute to the $DeptNo variable. You can then just pop that variable into the second parameter from the first example.